# how to force the control c within the shell script the shell script has ran,

Tags: php, shell

I have this shell script

```
php -f /export/home/prjck/htdocs/protected/yiic.php  SeleniumStartStop Killselenium
```

basically, what it does is , it rans a php script controller action.the problem is, whenever i ran this shell script..the cursor gets stuck at the beginning of a new line, I would have to press enter or control c of the keyboard in order to bring back the cursor beside the shell username...is there a way to insert some related command in order to not pressing the keyboard enter or control c whenever i ran the script?, so that everything is automated...

here's the usage stuff that i see whenever i ran the script( after the process was killed )

`$ kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
sh: line 0: kill: 18.3: arguments must be process or job IDs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start processes from the command line in the background by appending a `&`-sign at the end. Because php initializes a terminal for the output that will get stopped immediately, though. A workaround is to redirect the output to /dev/null.

```
php -f /export/home/prjck/htdocs/protected/yiic.php  SeleniumStartStop Killselenium > /dev/null &
```

Comment: i modified my post, please read the additional info that I added, maybe you can help me with it

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do or what's not working. Where does the kill command come from? Your php script? What should it do, what is happening?

Comment: yes it's coming from a php script, what it does is, it gets all the process that has "selenium", then I fetch all the PID of those processes that has selenium string with them..then I foreach loop through all the ID's and ran the ` shell_exec('kill -9 '. $pid);`

Comment: the killing of the processes is working, but as I said from the post, the kill usage message appears after the killing is done

Comment: From what you postet I would guess the problem is with your php script, see `sh: line 0: kill: 18.3: arguments must be process or job IDs`. I think you call kill with some invalid argument, hence the usage information.

Comment: yep, i've solved the issue earlier....there was an missing offset in the array..thanks though